# If else condition in document to control format of equation

Tags: equations, formatting, conditionals, ifthenelse

How can I create a variable in the beginning of the latex document that will dictate how certain equation will be shown? Concretely, in the beginning I want to define a variable `x` which will take value either `double column` or `single column`. Based on the value `x` takes, in the document certain equation will be one or the other. How can I do this? I put what I want in the comment here:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%set variable x = "double column"

\begin{document}

%if x == "double column" compile:
    \begin{equation}
        x = 2
    \end{equation}
%else compile:
    \begin{equation}
        y = 40
    \end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the `\if@twocolumn` conditional available at the user's level.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\let\iftwo\if@twocolumn
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\iftwo
  \begin{equation}
  c=2
  \end{equation}
\else
  \begin{equation}
  c=1
  \end{equation}
\fi
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**One column**

[image]

**Two column**

[image]

A more flexible approach that can save typing. Also the braces around the arguments to `\OneOrTwo` will avoid problems if the code is used inside `align` or similar environments.

```
\documentclass[twocolumn]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum} % for mock text

\makeatletter
\let\iftwo\if@twocolumn
\DeclareRobustCommand{\OneOrTwo}[2]{%
  \if@twocolumn#2\else#1\fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\iftwo
  \begin{equation}
  c=2
  \end{equation}
\else
  \begin{equation}
  c=1
  \end{equation}
\fi
\lipsum[1][1-4]
\begin{equation*}
  c=2
  \OneOrTwo{+long+long+long+long+long+long}
           {\begin{aligned}[t]&+long+long+long \\ &+long+long+long\end{aligned}}
\end{equation*}
\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

**One column**

[image]

**Two column**

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The basic approach of conditioning can be done in a number of ways. Here are a couple of ways:

- Define and compare macros/commands using `\ifx<cmdA><cmdB>`:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \newcommand{\myvar}{double column}
  \newcommand{\doublecolumn}{double column}

  \begin{document}

  \ifx\myvar\doublecolumn
    \begin{equation}
      x = 2
    \end{equation}
  \else
    \begin{equation}
      y = 40
    \end{equation}
  \fi

  \end{document}
  ```
- Compare your variable like one would normally, using a text comparison via `\pdfstrcmp{<stringA>}{<stringB>}`. This returns the number `0` if `<stringA>` equals `<stringB>` (-1/1 if `<stringA>` lexicographically precedes/succeeds `<stringB>`).

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \newcommand{\myvar}{double column}

  \begin{document}

  \ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\myvar}{double column}=0
    \begin{equation}
      x = 2
    \end{equation}
  \else
    \begin{equation}
      y = 40
    \end{equation}
  \fi

  \end{document}
  ```

  `\pdfstrcmp` expands its arguments, which is often helpful if they contain macros themselves. It's also available via [`pdftexcmds`](//ctan.org/pkg/pdftexcmds) if your engine doesn't provide it.
- Define a new `\if`-conditional:

  ```
  \documentclass{article}

  \newif\ifdoublecolumn% Default is \doublecolumnfalse

  \doublecolumntrue

  \begin{document}

  \ifdoublecolumn
    \begin{equation}
      x = 2
    \end{equation}
  \else
    \begin{equation}
      y = 40
    \end{equation}
  \fi

  \end{document}
  ```

  This option is more intuitive.

Comment: Maybe add that `\pdfstrcmp` isn't available in LuaTeX and that one should use a package adding it there (e.g., `pdftexcmds` which adds `\pdf@strcmp` in all engines).